# How to handle conditions in selenium Xpath

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am searching for a text in a table in web view, if text does not exist it should go to else and perform my operations accordingly, Instead of this, it throws an exception of NoSuchElementException. How to handle this. what Web drivers return a values when data is not found for comparison.

Note: this works fine if it find the matching value of `title` variable in table

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/div[6]/div/div[1]/div[2]/fieldset/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/table"));

// find the row
WebElement customer = table.findElement(By.xpath("//tbody/tr/td[contains(text(), '"+title+"')]/following-sibling::td/a[text()='Detail']"));
if(customer != null){ // how do I compare here.
    //System.out.println("This is your TITLE " +customer.getText());
    }else{
// my further code for failed case. 
}
```

Comment: According to the [docs](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-): "findElement should not be used to look for non-present elements, use findElements(By) and assert zero length response instead."

Comment: why you don't try some dependency that works with url [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html)

Comment: Alternatively, catch the NSEE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to look for an element that doesn't exist, a `NoSuchElementException` will indeed get thrown. Hence, use the `try / catch` mechanism in order to define the `else` case:

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/div[6]/div/div[1]/div[2]/fieldset/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/table"));
try {
    WebElement customer = table.findElement(By.xpath("//tbody/tr/td[contains(text(), '"+title+"')]/following-sibling::td/a[text()='Detail']"));
    System.out.println("This is your TITLE " +customer.getText()); 
}
catch(NoSuchElementException e) {
    // code for failed case
}
```

Alternatively, you can check if the element exists and then apply a regular `if / else`:

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/div[6]/div/div[1]/div[2]/fieldset/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/table"));
int amount = table.findElements(By.xpath("//tbody/tr/td[contains(text(), '"+title+"')]/following-sibling::td/a[text()='Detail']")).size();
if(amount > 0)
    // element exists
else
    // element doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:-

```
 public boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
  try {
        driver.findElement(by);
      return true;
     } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
         return false;
    }
}
```